# MySQL vs PostgreSQL ON DUPLICATE

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I would like to change my code in PostgreSQL to MySQL

PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO store VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
   ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT store_number_key DO UPDATE 
   SET quantity=store.quantity+EXCLUDED.quantity
```

I've got in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO store (name, producent, model, number, 
   quantity, warehouse, location) 
   VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quanity=quantity+VALUES(quantity)
```

It doesn't work, I don't know how should look like the query ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
What I want to achieve? When someone insert an item with the same magazine number the quantity should be sum up.

Comment: What does `It doesn't work` mean in your case. Do you get an error message when you execute the query, and if so what error message? Does it insert the wrong value and if so what value?

Comment: Why did you remove the sql queries form the question?

Comment: There is a typo in the MySQL query: `quanity` should be `quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

This query *should* work:

```
INSERT INTO store (name, producent, model, number, quantity, warehouse, location) 
   VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity);
```

However, it assumes that you have a unique index (or constraint) on the columns generating the conflict.  Your question gives no indication of what those columns are.